# all possible combinations using matlab

Tags: list, matlab, vector, combinations, factorial

If A=[1 1 2 2 2], I want all possible combinations of this vector.
Ans: R=[1 1 2 2 2; 1 2 1 2 2; 1 2 2 1 2; 1 2 2 2 1; 2 1 1 2 2; 2 1 2 1 2; 2 1 2 2 1; 2 2 1 2 1; 2 2 2 1 1; 2 2 1 1 2]
Is there some comand for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `perms` to get all permutations and remove the identical ones using `unique`

```
unique(perms([1,1,2,2,2]),'rows')
```